# How can I give a password as parameter using the Graph API for Azure-AD and Intune?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Following the example found here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/blob/master/Authentication/Auth_From_File.ps1

More specifically:

```
$UserPassword = get-Content "$Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$userCredentials = new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential -ArgumentList $userUPN,$UserPassword
$authResult = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext, $resourceAppIdURI, $clientid, $userCredentials).Result;
```

I've tried the following:

```
$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredentials = new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential -ArgumentList $userUPN,$UserPassword
$authResult = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext, $resourceAppIdURI, $clientid, $userCredentials).Result;
```

However, I've been getting the error that

> Authorization Access Token is null, please re-run authentication...

which can be found further in the code.

```
   if($authResult.AccessToken){
   [...]
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Authorization Access Token is null, please re-run authentication..." -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host
    break
```

Am I correct in thinking that I probably need to give the password in a different way?

Comment: In your example, `$password` is the plaintext password, yes? If so it looks okay. Have you tried inspecting `$authResult` after running you're three lines of code?

Comment: Hello Mathias. Yes, `$password` is the password in a normal string. How would I inspect `$authResult`?

Comment: You could execute the code line by line in the console (remember to assign values to all needed variables) and then afterwards pipe `$authResult` to `Get-Member` and/or `Format-List *` to see what's there

Comment: $authResult appears to be empty. Could it be that I'm giving the wrong password or otherwise doing something wrong?

Comment: This script was designed to use a password file, not a plain text password (`$password` is a reference to the file). See "Creating a password file" in the ReadMe @ https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/Authentication

Comment: Hi Marc. I know that it's designed to use a password file. I'd like to know if there is a way to get it to use plaintext instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I found whatever went wrong. I tried running another script and had to manually enter the credentials. This prompted me to accept a whole lot of permissions from Microsoft. I think that was the problem. This code now works:

```
$userId = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier" -ArgumentList ($User, "OptionalDisplayableId")

$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force

$userCredentials = new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential -ArgumentList $userUPN,$UserPassword

$authResult = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext, $resourceAppIdURI, $clientid, $userCredentials).Result;
```

Still, thank you Mathias and Marc for trying to help :)